# How to process arrow keys in CLI-based application, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface

I'm writing simple console Pomodoro timer (as my Haskell learning exercise):
[image: pomodoro-cli]

Until that time menu was based on the prompt line. But now I want to replace it with arrow-based menu, like in [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/):
[image: http://yeoman.io/codelab/install-generators.html]

How can I do it in Haskell?
I read about System.Console.Terminfo.Keys and other System.Console packages, but not found solution for my question.

Comment: Yes, @tbodt. This is just a case of the generic raw keyboard input problem. **How does one mark something as a duplicate?**

Comment: @Evi1M4chine You get 3,000 reputation, and then a "close" button appears under the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do that would be to use bindings to ncurses library. Infact [ncurses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses) shows you an example of handing the key character "Q" in their sample program.

Another nice Haskell solution is [vty-ui](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/) which has got a [nice documentation](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/manuals/vty-ui-users-manual-1.8.pdf) to it.